# ALSA - USB Interface - How to choose only one channel

Tags: audio, alsa, interface, recording

I am currently trying to record audio with ALSA and a USB interface. I am using a focusrite scarlett 4i4 3rd gen and a raspberry pi 4b with linux debian bookwarm installed.

My question is how do I select only one channel or a "slice" of channels. Right now I can only set channels by increasing the -c channel parameter:

`arecord -D plughw:CARD=3,DEV=0,SUBDEV=0 -f S32_LE -r 48000 -d 10 -c 4 RecordingTest_Ch4.wav`

But how can I acces the 4th channel but still only record mono. My interface is only getting recognized with one subdevice:

```
~ $ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 3: USB [Scarlett 4i4 USB], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and

```
~ $ arecord -L
hw:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 4i4 USB, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 4i4 USB, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=USB
    Scarlett 4i4 USB, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 4i4 USB, USB Audio
    Front output / input
dsnoop:CARD=USB,DEV=0
    Scarlett 4i4 USB, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
usbstream:CARD=USB
    Scarlett 4i4 USB
    USB Stream Output
```

Also I would like to record only the channels necassary. For example recording stereo with channels 1 and 4 could look something like this

```
arecord -D plughw:CARD=3,DEV=0,SUBDEV=[1,3] -f S32_LE -r 48000 -d 10 -c 2 RecordingTest_stereo.wav
```

Would be very happy if someone could help. Let me know if you need any further information.

Thanks in advance